# How do I open Instagram app from my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

I am trying to open the Instagram application from my iOS app through UIButton action but it's not working. It shows nothing.

Here is my code in Swift 3:

```
@IBAction func Instagram(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let instagramURL = URL(string: "instagram://app")!
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(instagramURL)
    }
```

[image: And here is my Plist Key -]

Comment: Please copy and paste your actual code into your question. The code you posted won't even compile.

Comment: And be sure to include the code that actually tries to open the Instagram app because the code you posted does not make any attempt to actually open the app.

Comment: This is the whole code that i used for opening instagram application.!

Comment: 1) That code doesn't compile so no, it's not your actual code. 2) That code makes no attempt to open Instagram.

Comment: Can you please give me the code to open instagram app?

Comment: Read the documentation for `UIApplication canOpenURL(_:)` and search on opening other apps. There are countless existing examples.

Comment: Let instagramURL = URL(string: "instagram:/app")!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(instagramURL)
}

Comment: Used this code but didn't worked.

Comment: Put that code in your question, not in comments.

Comment: And are you testing on a real iOS device that actually has the Instagram app installed?

Comment: yes..! I am testing on a real device, with instagram installed.

Comment: @AshishVerma The code I answered is working fine. You are using a deprecated `openURL` method for iOS 10 and also there is a typo in your instagram open url which you posted in comment. Check my answer

Comment: @AshishVerma Have you verified that your `Instagram(_:)` function is actually being called when you tap the button?

Comment: yes.! its working

Comment: @rmaddy Its now working.! there was a problem in Plist - Thanks for the Help.!

Comment: @AshishVerma You should either post your own answer that clearly explains what you had wrong and what you did to fix it, or you should delete your question.

Answer (score 5):

For swift 4.2+ and ios 9+
This code launch Instagram, if it's not installed, launch the Instagram profile page in a web browser.

```
    let screenName =  "mehdico" // CHANGE THIS

    let appURL = URL(string:  "instagram://user?username=\(screenName)")
    let webURL = URL(string:  "https://instagram.com/\(screenName)")

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(appURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(appURL)
        }
    } else {
        //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Instagram
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(webURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(webURL)
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's with the inconsistent use of optionals and NSURL instead of simply URL?

Comment: @Clashsoft Thank you for your note. the code is updated now.

Answer (score 3):

The method `openUrl` which you have posted in comments in deprecated too in iOS 10

Use this

```
@IBAction func openInstagramButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let instagram = URL(string: "instagram://app")!

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagram) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(instagram, options: ["":""], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            print("Instagram not installed")
    }
}
```

For the first time it will prompt you to open or cancel.

Also make sure to do the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` entry for instagram which you had already done.

Comment: No its not working, As there is no action after clicking the button.!

Comment: Its working. Check your button outlet. Keep a debugger inside the button

Comment: Wow, now the working code too get downvotes, hopefully SO should make a feature to upload a short execution video.

Comment: Using the deprecated `openURL` is not an issue.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh, so thats the reason for downvote, Amazing

Comment: if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(instagram, options: ["":""], completionHandler: nil)

Comment: @AshishVerma It is a working code executed on Xcode 8.1 and tested on iOS 10.1 version device.

Comment: I am using xcode 8 and ios 10 .! Is that the problem ? @RajanMaheshwari

Comment: what is happening, what is the error? Debug the code line by line.

Comment: There is no error on clicking - as it shows nothing on debugger.

Comment: What nothing on debugger, Be specific. Where is the flow on code going? It should atleast go to button function. I am not saying Logs, I am asking to put a Debugger

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Its now working.! there was a problem in Plist - Thanks for the Help.!

Comment: @AshishVerma If it helped, Kindly accept as a tick.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Why is the down vote amazing? You posted an answer that claimed the cause of the problem was due to using a deprecated API. But that had nothing at all to do with the issue.

Comment: @rmaddy Have you read the answer? Where in the blue hell is written that the deprecated URL is the reason for the problem. I was just informing the OP to try non deprecated methods and stay updated. Dont make assumptions by your own.

Comment: @rmaddy Certainly you are carrying a lot of points, so a negative won't affect you as much as it can affect others especially on the working code. You can always downvote for an answer which is not correct or buggy.

Comment: I'm not making any assumptions. Your answer points out the use of a deprecated method. You post a bunch of code using the new, non-deprecated method and suggest that that code be used. This is what you put on your answer. But none of that is relevant to the issue. The use of the deprecated method isn't the problem. Your answer doesn't solve the issue. I'm simply pointing out this fact. A down vote is an indication of an answer that isn't helpful in solving the issue in the question. It's not personal.

Comment: Well again I would like to remind you that its the OP's choice to accept that answer and decide it is helpful to him or not. And after the conversation with OP, I found exactly what I thought. What the title of the question says, I guess the answer posted should be fine for it.